# static variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to create a static variable in java script. My requirement is "i created a global variable as var a = 'ABC'. But i am changing the variable value when i am doing some interaction with DOM. If i refresh the Page i want the latest value to be shown. is it Possible?"

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Static variable</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick = "staticDemo();">Click Me</button>
        <script>
            var a = "ABC";
            alert(a);
            function staticDemo(){
                a = "DEF";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not possible in that way. If you refresh the page the whole page including the script will be created new.

Comment: It's not possible unless you are running some sort of server side code. The scope of a JavaScript variable on a page is there until the page is reloaded or refreshed, then then whole script is loaded once again.

Comment: Refreshing the page is equivalent to restarting your compiled program, lets says in 'C' . in that case values of static variables in your last execution is not persistent in the current execution. best case for you is store that initial value in localstorage or in a db, then when your program starts you initialize your variable with stored value

Comment: Sounds like a case for cookies... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage for retrieve data, even after refresh. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp